# Using MEL to fetch URL in HTTP OUTBOUND ENDPOINT

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

I have an requirement where I have to consume an rest service over HTTPS and I have to fetch the URL in runtime .
To accomplish the same I am setting the REST 'url' as a  outbound property and I am trying to fetch that using MEL

```
#[message.outboundProperties.'url'
```

When try to do as I said above , I am getting compile time error which is mentioned below

```
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'protocol' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address '#[message.outboundProperties.'url']' for protocol 'http' should start with http://
```

Am I doing anything wrong ? or is there a best way to achieve this requirement other than this ?

```html
 <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
         method="GET" doc:name="HTTPs with Auth header" address="#[message.outboundProperties.'url']" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>

    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-key-store path="#[message.outboundProperties.'Storepath']" keyPassword="#[message.outboundProperties.'storepassword']" storePassword="#[message.outboundProperties.'storepassword']"/>
        <https:tls-server path="#[message.outboundProperties.'Storepath']" storePassword="#[message.outboundProperties.'storepassword']"/>
    </https:connector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http components requires a static 'HTTP://' as the beginning of the URL hence the below  works

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://#[message.outboundProperties.'url'] " doc:name="HTTP"/>
```